# EntityFramework Database.EnsureCreated() trying to create mdf in wrong path

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having weird issues with method Database.EnsureCreated() of Entity Framework core. It happens on many computers with clean installations.

As you can see it tries to create the mdf file with this path

**c:\Users\AdminBLTManager.mdf**

While it should be:

**c:\Users\Admin\BLTManager.mdf**

[image: Terminal showing errors]

The code is nothing special:

```
class CreateInitialDataIfDbIsEmptyBgService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CreateInitialDataIfDbIsEmptyBgService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<MigrateDatabaseBgService> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        _logger.LogWarning("Ensuring database exists...");
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

        _logger.LogWarning("Ensuring initial admin user exists when db is newly created...");
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

this is run in ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddHostedService<CreateInitialDataIfDbIsEmptyBgService>();
```

The weird thing is this is happening only to some computers, not on my development environment.

EDIT:

Connection string:

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=BLTManager;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

},

Registering the ApplicationDbContext:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
  .....
}
```

Comment: The issue might be relates the permission, try to run the application using the Administrator.

Comment: @ZhiLv it's running as Administrator, the problem is it's trying to create the MDF file in c:\Users\AdminBLTManager.mdf instead of c:\Users\Admin\BLTManager.mdf you can see it doesn't append a \ before file name BLTManager.mdf

Comment: Can you share the connection string and how to do you register the ApplicationDbContext with the connection string?

Comment: @ZhiLv added to question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an old LocalDB bug [we hit once](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/384). I think it was fixed sometime after the initial 2017 release. Try updating to see if it goes away.